# Prediction from smooths with linear functionals in gam mgcv

Tags: r, gam, mgcv

I am working on a large bam model in R with smooths, including linear functional terms via matrix predictors and 'by' variables. We are exploring  how disturbance intensity and time since disturbance can influence current response. The observations are a vector of bird presence/absence data taken every 2 minutes. We are fitting a matrix of 2 minute time lags with a matrix 'by' variable of lagged presence/absence of disturbance, and including two disturbance types in the same model.

```
bam(Bird ~ s(TimeLag,by=Disturbance1History, bs="gp")+ s(TimeLag,by=Disturbance2History, bs="gp"),family=binomial())
```

I have fit the model and created a new data object that is a list of all elements of the model. This includes matrices with dimensions matching those from the model, as this is a requirement of `predict.gam` when fitting such a model. The goal is to predict response using a matrix 'by' variable with altered disturbance levels. This is done to explore how degree of exposure to disturbance influences birds over time, especially in the context of histories of other disturbance types.

*So, how do you plot predicted response data with matrix predictors and 'by' variables?*

Here are some data and simple models with predictions to help illustrate:

```
    library(data.table)
    library(mgcv)
    library(tidyverse)
```

Four hours of bird presence/absence taken once every two minutes, and corresponding data for two disturbance types, "Dist1" and "Dist2".

```
    BirdRaw<-c(1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,
             1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,
             1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,
             1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,1)

    Dist1Raw<-c(1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,
              1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,
              1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,
              1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1)

    Dist2Raw<-c(0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,
              0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,
              0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,
              0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0)

    df<-data.table(Bird=BirdRaw, Dist1=Dist1Raw, Dist2=Dist2Raw)
```

We have our observations of bird and disturbance types, and now choose a time window of interest to explore the effects of disturbance. We'll use a 20 minute window, so 10 lags.

```
    LagWindow <- 10 # 10 surveys, so 20 minute window
```

Now create matrices of 20 minutes of disturbance history, and drop the first 20 minutes of data so that all rows are complete.

```
    Dist1Hist<-df[,shift(Dist1,1:LagWindow)]%>% drop_na("V10")
    Dist2Hist<-df[,shift(Dist2,1:LagWindow)]%>% drop_na("V10")
```

Create a time lag matrix of equal dimension:

```
    LagHist <- matrix(rep(2*(1:LagWindow),dim(Dist1Hist)[1]),
    ncol=LagWindow, byrow=T)
```

Response variable, matched up with lag matrices:

```
    BirdHist<-df[,shift(Dist1,1:LagWindow)][, "Bird" := df[,Bird]]%>%
drop_na("V10")
    Bird<-BirdHist$Bird

#remove some objects
    rm(df, BirdRaw,BirdHist ,Dist1Raw, Dist2Raw, LagWindow)
```

Fit and plot the model:

```
    mod1<- bam(Bird ~ s(LagHist,by=as.matrix(Dist1Hist), bs="gp")+
    + s(LagHist,by=as.matrix(Dist2Hist),
    bs="gp"),family=binomial())

    plot(mod1, pages=1,xlab="Time since disturbance")
    summary(mod1)
```

Predict from observed data. First, create a new data object that is a named list of all elements from the model, including matrices with matching dimensions.

```
    Dist1Hist<-as.matrix(Dist1Hist)
    Dist2Hist<-as.matrix(Dist2Hist)
    pdlistReal<-list(Dist1Hist, Dist2Hist, LagHist, Bird)
    names(pdlistReal)<-c("Dist1Hist", "Dist2Hist", "LagHist", "Bird")

    predReal<-predict(mod1,pdlistReal, type="response",se.fit=TRUE)
```

I also want to predict bird response for cases when disturbance history is decreased, and with all other variables as they appear in the model.

Create new data matrix for Dist1 with all 0's, and create a new data list for prediction.

```
    #multiply by 0
    Dist1Hist<-Dist1Hist*0

    #create list of elements for new data prediction with decreased Dist1 history
    pdlistND<-list(Dist1Hist, Dist2Hist, LagHist, Bird)
    names(pdlistND)<-c("Dist1Hist", "Dist2Hist", "LagHist", "Bird")
    predND<-predict(mod1,pdlistND, type="response",se.fit=TRUE)
```

Predicted fits:

```
    head(predReal)
    head(predND)
```

Now, I would like to plot the predicted fit and SE from objects "predReal" and "predND" against the time variable, LagHist. The plots should be similar to the result of `plot(mod1)` with x-axes from 0-20 minutes and the y axis on the response scale. Hopefully there is a simple way to plot these predictions, and I'm just not thinking of it.

Any help is appreciated and thank you for your time!

-Nate

Comment: Hi njk, thanks for taking time to prepare the data for the question. I can run your code, and roughly catch what you want to know. So maybe split your question into 2 separate questions? One part about whether gaussian smooth is suitable and second about visualizing the results?

Comment: And you can also take some of the commented questions inside your code block into actual text..

Comment: Thank you. I've streamlined the question. I appreciate your help.